# Fill DropDownList items by selected item in another DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<table><tr>
   <td>
      Type:
   </td>
    <td>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddltype" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddltype_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">---select---</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Setter" Value="1">
       </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Getter" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
       <td>
          Name:
       </td>
            <td>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlname" runat="server">
              </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
 </tr> </table>
```

If user select either `setter` or `getter` in first dropdownlist, I want to fill the related names in second dropdownlist. How can I write code in c# page for this requirement. Please help me anyone.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.
You want to show the text of the selected item? I suppose after Name: in your second table cell?

Comment: So you want to filter _something_ according to the value the user selected (`Getter` or `Setter`). But _what_ do you want to filter and what have you tried?

Comment: In "ddltype_SelectedIndexChanged" you can get ddltype.selcected value. Based on that create logic to get the related name and bind to the next dropdown "ddlname".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void NamesToDropdownList()
{
        objhatcheryPL.type = ddltype.SelectedItem.Text;
        DataTable dtname = new DataTable();
        dtname = objhatcheryBAL.dtnames(objhatcheryPL);
        ddlname.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlname.DataValueField = "Name";
        ddlname.DataSource = dtname;
        ddlname.DataBind();
        ddlname.Items.Add(new ListItem("--select--", "0"));
        ddlname.SelectedIndex = ddlname.Items.Count - 1;
 }

protected void ddltype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (ddltype.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
    {
        NamesToDropdownList();
    }
   }
```

with this my code is working perfectly....